# Legendrian surgery and invertible elements in zeroth degree symplectic cohomology

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry

Is there anything known about the relation between Legendrian handle attachment and invertible elements in $\mathit{SH}^0(M)$?

As the simplest interesting case, take $M_0$ to be the cotangent bundle $T^\ast T^2$, then $\mathit{SH}^0(M_0)\cong\mathbb{K}[x^\pm,y^\pm]$. Both $x,y$ and the identity $e$ are invertible generators in $\mathit{SH}^0(M_0)$. Since $M_0$ is the complement of the toric divisor in $\mathbb{CP}^2$, so smoothing out one of the nodes of the toric divisor is equivalent to attaching a 2-handle to $M_0$. This leads to the Weinstein 4-manifold $M_1$, which is the complement of a conic in $\mathbb{C}^2$, and it's shown by Pascaleff that $\mathit{SH}^0(M_1)\cong\mathbb{K}[x,y,(xy-1)^{-1}]$, so $xy-1$ and $e$ are invertible elements. If we start with $M_1$ and smooth out another node in the toric divisor, we arrive at the Weinstein 4-manifold $M_2$, which is the hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^3$ defined by the equation $x+y+xyz=1$. In terms of Legendrian surgery, $M_2$ is the result of attaching a 2-handle along a trefoil knot in the boundary of $D^4$. Using known computations of the Legendrian contact homology of the trefoil knot, we conclude that $\mathit{SH}^0(M_2)\cong\mathbb{K}[x,y,z]/(x+y+xyz-1)$, there is no invertible element other than non-zero multiples of $e$. If we further smooth out the remaining node in the toric divisor, $M_3$ is the complement of a smooth elliptic curve in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. In this case, the recent work of Ganatra-Pomerlano shows that $\mathit{SH}^0(M_3)\cong\mathbb{K}[x]$ is the polynomial ring generated by the Borman-Sheridan class, so again $e$ and its non-zero multiples are the only invertible elements. One can attach more handles and if they are attached in an appropriate way, one gets the unimodal Milnor fibers studied by Keating, and one can show for those manifolds, there is no invertible element in $\mathit{SH}^0(M)$ other than non-zero multiples of $e$.

It seems (at least by looking at the examples above) that Legendrian surgery potentially kills invertible elements in $\mathit{SH}^0(M)$, and Legendrian anti-surgery potentially creates new invertible elements. Is this something that is expected to be true in general?